# Using BASH to store and loop MySQL fetched results?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, bash, shell

I'm not very familiar with Bash and Shell scripting, but my long term goal here is to write a bash script that will grab data from a MySQL table. For every result found I want to execute a PHP file that will have an extention of '?result=bashvariable'.

How would I go about grabbing the SQL data in bash and storing it in a variable?

In PHP I would simply fetch the results and run a while loop, I am just wondering if this is possible with bash?

I apologize if this is a duplicate of some sort, but I have yet to find the answer I'm searching for.

Comment: Why not just use the PHP in CLI mode?

Comment: whats the point of adding bash in to this at all? Reads like an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem.

Comment: What would the `while`-loop do in PHP, if you're feeding it just 1 result at a time? And why not query your database from PHP in the first place?

Comment: For every result found I want to run a PHP script that does something different per result. That is why I'm thinking Bash is my best solution.

Comment: it can be done in php with exec() et al

Comment: Why not just one run PHP script that performs the query, and does something different depending on the result in each row?

Comment: @Barmar When I do that I'm getting a fatal error with my functions; but I was doing it via include prior to thinking that Bash would be a better solution.

Comment: bash has no mysql drivers. you can't fetch data row by row, unless you run one query per row and feed it into mysql with `$ mysql < query1.sql; mysql < query2.sql; etc...`.

Comment: then it is an XY problem, ask about the original issue, not your purposed (bash) solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql -e 'yourquery' database | while read bashvariable
do
  php file.php "$bashvariable"
done
```

The PHP script can access the bash variable as `$argv[1]`.

Comment: You can't use a query string like that on the CLI. `# php file.php "$bashvariable"` and then reference `$argv` inside the script.

Comment: This seems to have worked for me. I appreciate it greatly Barmar.